# Condition mako base template from inheriting one

Tags: python, pylons, mako

I have a base.mako template with a if statement to include or not jQuery

```
<head>
% if getattr(c, 'includeJQuery', False):
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
% endif
...
```

Several templates inherit from base.mako, someone needs jQuery, someone don't.

At the moment I have to set the attribute in the controller before calling render

```
c.includeJQuery = True
return render('/jQueryTemplate.mako')
```

but I think this *should* go directly in child template (i.e. jQueryTemplate.mako)

I tried adding it before inherit

```
<% c.includeJQuery = True %>
<%inherit file="/base.mako"/>\
```

but it does not work.

Any tips?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using "c" in your template.

```
<% includeJquery = True %>
```

and

```
% if includeJquery:
...
% endif
```

should suffice.

I think you are doing this wrong...  In your base template you should make a blank def for a jquery block and call it.  Then in the inherited template just redefine the block.

base.mako:

```
<head>
${self.jquery()}
</head>

<%def name="jquery()"></%def>
```

Then in another template you add jquery with:

```
<%inherit file="base.mako />

<%def name="jquery()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</%def>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, since with the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I also need to add some other js I put a jQueryScript %def in child template

```
##jQueryTemplate.mako
<%def name="jQueryScript()">
    <script>
    </script>
</%def>
```

then in base I check if exists and add all accordingly

```
#base.mako
%if hasattr(next, 'jQueryScript'):
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    ${next.jQueryScript()}
%endif
```

so I don't need to set nothing in the controller.